# After delisting in Spam-Filter (SORBS) still blocked

Tags: domains, smtp, spam-blocker

weeks ago I had to unblock a webdomain from SORBS.net. They listed my Website (IP) as a spam and we weren't able to write E-Mails to some most of our customers (mostly company-mail-addresses).
So I delisted our Website and got unblocked. Now two or three weeks after that we are still blocked from the most Spam-Filter.

https://mxtoolbox.com/ is clean in blacklists and SMTP-checks.

What can I do that we reach our customers again?
Is my IP still cached in their system and we have to wait until it gets refreshed (maybe in a month or a year)? If yes, is there a workaround I can do?

Comment: Websites have very little to do with mail servere - why do you think fixing web connectivity will help with mail connectivity.  The work-arround is ti relay your email through a reputable mta provider.

Comment: As you may already know, I am no specialist in these topics, but I thought it will help because its a hosting package with web and smtp (same IP) and this got blocked. Thanks for the hint to the mta.

Comment: Whats your donain name?

Comment: @Michael have you checked your IP reputation at https://talosintelligence.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments i read about the mta provider and found out, that our provider itself offers this service for free.
After setting up the mta provider everythings fine again.